# How to store the template files in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have one dock window created in EA and it is displaying the xml file contents in tree view but the problem is if we exit EA and open the same eap file again the dock window with tree view contents doesn't appear.So we want to store the tree contents in eap file such that if we reopen the eap file we want the dock window to read the tree contents and display it.

Comment: You mean then CodeEng./Source Viewer does not appear again?

Comment: If we move the eap file to another system then the path of the file doesnot exists there so the source viewer doesnot display file contents

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Tools/Directories and Paths`. You can use "%"-enclosed names to define paths so you can use it from different environments. That's the only option you have here. There's a help button with the dialog that pops up which explains its use.